# Dishwasher tiny leak in front on second cycle

Tags: dishwasher, samsung

We just bought and self installed a Samsung DW50T6060 dishwasher. We ran the express cycle fully with detergent but no dishes. All good. Then we loaded it up and started a normal cycle. A few minutes later it gives us the LC code. We pulled it out and there is just a quarter sized water puddle a few inches back from where the door is. No other leaks. Sink disposal works fine and the knockout plug is knocked out.

Confused because it ran fine the first time. We didn't overload it or anything. Any ideas?

(Please don't tell me not to buy Samsung; we already did.)

Comment: the machine is under warranty ... you should be taking to Samsung tech support

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally jam a tupperware top or some such in the door?

Comment: It might help us help you if you told us what "the LC code" means - you've got the documentation to hand and we'd have to go look it up...

Answer (score 0):

Clean around the door gasket and check it for damage. If there is a problem clean it. If that is not the problem call for warranty service. You can reach Samsung by phone at 1-800-SAMSUNG.

Good Luck and clean dishes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the sump had a giant hole. We're getting the machine replaced.